# Sencha Touch, upon firing an event, show the password the user typed inside a passwordfield

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In a Sencha Touch view config I have a psswordfield:

```
{
    // Password.
    xtype: 'passwordfield',
    placeHolder: 'Password',
    itemId: 'registerViewPasswordField',
}
```

I have delegated an event, and the user can check if he wants to see the password or not.

```
listeners: [
   {
        delegate: '#registerViewShowPassword',
        event: 'check',
        fn: 'onRegisterViewShowPasswordCheck'
    },{
        delegate: '#registerViewShowPassword',
        event: 'uncheck',
        fn: 'onRegisterViewShowPasswordUncheck'
    }
]
```

If the user clicks to show the password, how can I turn the "password" field into a "textfield", how can I show the actual password that the user has entered?

```
onRegisterViewShowPasswordCheck: function() {
    // how can I make the "passwordfield" show the password the user just typed?
}
```

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a textfield under the password field and make it hidden by default, then when you need to, hide the password field and show the regular field.

```
{
    // Password.
    xtype: 'passwordfield',
    placeHolder: 'Password',
    itemId: 'registerViewPasswordField'
},
{
    // Visible password.
    xtype: 'textfield',
    placeHolder: 'Password',
        hidden: true,
    itemId: 'registerVisiblePasswordField'
}
```

Then inside your `onRegisterViewShowPasswordCheck` method, toggle the visibility of both fields.